# Need help upgrading EE along with PHP on my website

Tags: php

I have a website built in ExpressionEngine but my developer is no longer working with freelance clients. I recently received a notice from my hosting company that my website's PHP is out of date and I have until March 1 to upgrade to PHP 7.2 or start paying an $8 monthly fee. I am looking for a developer who could help me with upgrading both EE and PHP so my site keeps working and I can avoid the monthly fee. Willing to pay of course! Not quite sure how this board works and if you'll be able to email me off of this post - let me know if you need additional information. Thanks!

Comment: You should add the information about which version of EE you are running and which addons (incl. versions) you are using. This will help potential commercial partners to give an estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading EE can be challenging, particularly if you are starting on EE2 or earlier.  See my [answer to an earlier question on this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/40176/expression-engine-upgrade-from-2-to-3-to-4/) for more.

There are many people and firms around who can help you - including JCOGS Design!  I am not sure what options exist for person-to-person communications via StackExchange, or what the policy is for including contact info in answers is: but you can grab a link to the [JCOGS Design](https://jcogs.net) website from the [stackexchange profile](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/6060/jcogs-eecms).  Get in touch using the contact info there (or email contact (at) jcogs (dot) net and we can discuss your options for getting the upgrade done etc.

If you would like to widen the search, a good place to post your request is the "Jobs" channel in the [Expression Engine Slack](https://eecms.slack.com/): many highly experienced EE wranglers hang out there, and I'm sure you will quickly get multiple responses to your request.

HTH